# Ubuntu server version, USB installation, fail in choose archive mirror

Tags: networking, usb-installation, mirrors

I download the *Ubuntu server version 16.04* from official site:  `ubuntu-16.04.2-server-amd64.iso`

I create the Created a Bootable USB from this ISO.

In the install process, there is a step ask me to choose a archive mirror

Does installing Ubuntu server version using USB requires network connection?

How can I install Ubuntu server OS without being able to connect my PC to the Internet?

Comment: Ubuntu Server should offer you the option to install without a live internet connection. The archive mirror dialog should only set up repository mirror servers, not actually access them at that time. What exactly goes wrong?